# Extract grid's records into an object

Tags: sencha-test, sencha-test-2.1

Say I have a grid and want to extract its records.

```
let record = {};
grid.rowAt(rowIndex) 
    .cellAt(cellIndex)
    .focus()
    .get('innerText')
    .and(function (future) {
        record.columnName = future.data.innerText;
    });
```

How can I figure out how many columns and rows a grid has?

Based on the column's index how can I get the name of the respective header?

Comment: While @Daniel Gallo 's answer probably works most of the time, for me it was necessary to add `.rowAt(0, 60000).grid()` before calling the `execute(...)` function because the grid's entries are loaded dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following examples should help demonstrate how to get the row count, column count, get a column's title, and get the record object from a row in an Ext JS grid using Sencha Test:

```
describe('Grid', function() {
    beforeAll(function() {
        ST.grid('array-grid')
            .rowAt(0);      // Wait for data to be in the grid
    });

    it('should check the total number of rows and columns', function() {
        ST.grid('array-grid')
            .execute(function(grid) {
                var values = {
                    recordCount: grid.getStore().getCount(),    // Get the Store count (same as row count)
                    columnCount: grid.query('gridcolumn:visible').length    // Get the number of visible columns
                };

                return values;
            })
            .and(function(future) {
                var result = future.data.executeResult;

                expect(result.recordCount).toEqual(100);
                expect(result.columnCount).toEqual(6);
            });
    });

    it('should get the column title for the fifth column in the grid', function() {
        var columnTitle;

        ST.component('array-grid gridcolumn:visible:nth-child(5)')
            .get('text')
            .and(function(future) {
                // Do something with the column title
                columnTitle = future.data.text;

                expect(columnTitle).toEqual('Last Updated');
            });
    });

    it('should get the record for the third grid row and check some of its values', function() {
        ST.grid('array-grid')
            .rowAt(2)
            .getRecord()
            .and(function(future) {
                var record = future.data.record;

                expect(record.name).toEqual('Dabvine');
                expect(record.price).toEqual(29.94);
            });
    });
});
```